# iOS: xcodebuild command add argument to "Header Search Paths" in Build Settings

Tags: ios, cordova, terminal, command, xcodebuild

I have a problem with the `xcodebuild archive` command.

I get the following error:

> Cordova/CDVViewController.h not found

I know that I have to add in the build settings in 'Header Search Paths' 'Release' following line:

```
"$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include"
```

Now I have to add this line to the build settings via the xcodebuild CLI's.
I tried something like this:

```
xcodebuild archive -project App.xcodeproj -scheme App -archivePath App.xcarchive ENABLE_BITCODE=NO HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS_Release="$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include"
```

But it did not work.
How can I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YLsm.png)

Comment: Hi. It is should be: `-configuration "Release" HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS="$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include"`

Comment: @Mozilla thanks for the fast answer .
I get the following error in the terminal: 
-bash: OBJROOT: command not found
-bash: PLATFORM_NAME: command not found
How can I solve this?

Comment: If you build your project manually you should know `PLATFORM_NAME`. Open the folder "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/" and select a platform (the simulator or real device). Then set it to path "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/xxxxx/include".

Comment: The command does not work, 
i still get this error: Cordova/CDVViewController.h not found

Comment: Please, post a final version of your script and content of the `"$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/`. Is present `CDVViewController.h` inside of the `"$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/` ?

Comment: I think i have to pass HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS 5 paramters. You can see the parameters in the image-link above.
My current script looks like this :
xcodebuild archive -project App.xcodeproj -scheme App -archivePath App.xcarchive -configuration "Release" ENABLE_BITCODE=NO HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS=...

How can i pass HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS this parameters?

Comment: `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS="/first/xxx" "second/xxx" "etc/xxx"`